# Checking Independence of combination of uniform random variables to use pilling up lemma

Tags: linear-cryptanalysis, probability

My question is very basic one. Suppose $a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, b_0, b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4$ are $10$ uniform random variables from $\{0,1\}$ independent of each other. Now there are expressions of the form

1. $a_4b_4 + a_3(b_0 + b_2+1) + b_3(a_0 + a_2 +1) + a_1(b_2 + b_4) + b_1(a_2 +a_4)$
2. $a_2b_0 + a_1b_1 + (a_0 + a_2 +1)b_2$

Can we apply Pilling up lemma? Or alternatively are the random variables $a_4b_4, a_3(b_0 + b_2+1), b_3(a_0 + a_2 +1), a_1(b_2 + b_4), b_1(a_2 +a_4)$ independent in case 1?
Similarly are $a_2b_0 , a_1b_1 , (a_0 + a_2 +1)b_2$ independent in case 2 ?

How to show independence or dependency? Can anyone please help me understand these?

p.s - I can't find suitable tags other than linear-cryptoanalyzes. Anyone who can better tag the question is always welcome.

Comment: The plus is x-or, rigth? You can use `\oplus` for this. And, note that Piling-Up lemma about x-oring not and. And is destructive and creates bias!.

Comment: yes the plus is x-or.

Answer (score 1):

For $2$, it's easy to see these variables are independents because each elementary variables which appear in one of the expressions doesn't appear in the other.

For example

$\mathbb{P}(a_2b_0=0| a_1b_1=0, b_2(a_0 + a_2 +1)=0) = \mathbb{P}(a_4b_4=0)$.

A good way to see this, I think is to look the entropy of one of this variable :

$H (a_2 b_0 |a_1 b_1, b_2(a_0 + a_2 +1) ) \geq 
H (a_2 b_0 |a_0, a_1, b_1, b_2 ) = H (a_2 b_0  )$.

The last equality comes from the independence of the elementary variables.

Thus we can deduce $H (a_2 b_0 |a_1 b_1, b_2(a_0 + a_2 +1) )= H (a_2 b_0  ) $.

About $1$, it's more complex because $b_4, b_2, a_2, a_4$ appear in more than one expression.

Then you have to show that $a_4, b_4, a_3, (b_0 + b_2), b_3, (a_0 + a_2), a_1 ,(b_2 + b_4), b_1, (a_2 + a_4)$ are linearly independent in $\mathbb{F}_2$ (by doing linear algebra), thus you can deduce these variables (eventually plus a constant) are independents (from a probabilistic point of view).

And then you have to use the argument "if $X, Y, Z, T$ are independent, then $XY$ and $ZT$ are independents."

Edit : A good way to see the independence of the linear variables is to compute the determinant of the following matrix (the first line correspond to $a_4$, the second to $b_4$, the fourth to $b_0 + b_2$, etc), you can also proof these family of vector generates $\mathbb{F}^{10}_p$, and deduce by the cardinality, it's base, and thus the vectors are independents :

$\begin{matrix}  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}$

Comment: thank you for your elaborative answer. Entropy is a little bit advanced for me. The linear algebra part you suggested to use is basically to show that if $c_1a_4 + c_2b_4 + \cdots = 0$ holds then all the coefficients $c_1, c_2, ..$ are zero ?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. That's it.

Comment: So then the coefficients of $(b_2 + b_4), (a_2 + a_4)..$ are to be broken right ? And then we have to use the fact that $b_2, b_4,...$ are linearly independent. In that way the random variables are linearly dependent as some of the coefficients with non zero value is coming. Am I wrong somewhere ?

Comment: What do you mean by "broken right"?

Comment: Also what about the $+1$ part ? I meant its $a_2 +a_4 +1$ right. I am stumbling to understand. Can you clear it out ? Thank you

Comment: By broken I meant $c_1 a_4 + \cdots + c_k (a_2 + a_4) + \cdots = 0$ implies $(c_1 + c_k)a_4 +c_k a_2 + \cdots $ ?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $X+1$ are independent. So you have to consider the homogeneous version of an equation to look the linear independence, but then when you can add "+1" without changing the probabilistic independence.

Comment: You can do this to show the linear independence, but I've proposed to you two other techniques : Compute the determinant of the associate matrix, or prove it's a base of the vector space (by showing it generates all the canonical vector).

Comment: You meant $X+1$ and $Y+1$ or $X+1$ and $Y$  are independent ? Also that $c_1, c_2, ...$ is very understandable to me so that's why I am trying to show in that way.

Comment: About the "+1" Both are true, because the variables are in $\{0, 1\}$, it's easy to see by considering the definition.

Comment: So, if you use the $c_i$'s techniques, you can deduce that each coefficient of the $a_i$'s are zero, because the $a_i$'s and the $b_i$'s are linearly independent (they form the canonical base).

Comment: Yes. I have understood. Thanks for your time. Almost lightened up.

Comment: One more question, by the help conditional probability we can show that $X, Y$ independent then $X+1, Y$ is independent. Now we can show this independence also by showing $c_1 (X+1) +c_2(Y) = 0 \implies c_1 X + c_2 Y + c_1 = 0 $ from that we must  have to $c_1 = 0 = c_2$, so from $c_1 X + c_2 Y = c_1$  can we say $c_1 = c_2 = 0 $ ? Because we have to assume $c_1  =0$ to use the independence of $X$ and $Y$. Is that true ? @levgeni

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126509/discussion-between-ievgeni-and-hiren-garai).